# Can I use regular expression for job name in kubernetes python client?

Tags: python, regex, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm a very new user of k8s python client.

I'm trying to find the way to get jobs with regex in python client.

For example in CLI,

`kubectl describe jobs -n mynamespace partial-name-of-job`

gives me the number of jobs whose name has `partial-name-of-job` in "mynamespace".

I'm trying to find the exact same code in python client.

I did several searches and some are suggested to use label selector, but the python client API function `BatchV1Api().read_namespaced_job()` requires the exact name of jobs.

Please let me know if there's a way!

Comment: Hi @N Lee, welcome to the SO club ) Do you mean k8s [BatchV1PIi](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md) ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [read_namespaced_job](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#read_namespaced_job) doesn't allow to filter jobs with name pattern.

There is [list_namespaced_job](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#list_namespaced_job) that have `field_selector` argument.  But `field_selector` supports a limited list of operators:

> You can use the =, ==, and != operators with field selectors (= and == mean the same thing).

So, if you want to apply regex filter to job list, I'd suggest to get full list and then filter it using [Python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl describe jobs` (it describes all jobs in default namespace) instead of returning the number of jobs.

So as mentioned by [Yasen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57722892/11207414) please use [list_namespaced_job](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#list_namespaced_job) with `namespace` parameter it gives api request like `kubectl get --raw=/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/jobs`

You can also modify your script and get some specific value. Please run `kubectl get or describe --v=8` to get the strict api request. 
Please refer to [Kubectl output verbosity and debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging)

Hope this help